# Threads - Pre-emptive Mutitasking vs. Priorities

Tags: multithreading, time, operating-system

In my understanding, pre-emptive multitasking is the case when a time-slice (e.g. a 1 millisecond time-slice) makes the scheduler (of the OS) pass (to the CPU) one thread to the CPU for a particular span of time (1 millisecond in this example) and then switches to another thread (executes it for 1 millisecond and then switches back to the first thread and so on - assuming that there are only two threads, for simplicity).
Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsERPf9k54U

In contrast to pre-emptive multi-tasking is the concept of priorities - the OS sets priorities of applications in numbers, e.g. 1 to 39 etc., on whatever basis - that is not the concern for now.

And the advantage of this is that if one application hangs, the time-slicer simply goes back to the other thread (let's say this thread belongs to a different application, and the first application has hanged) and continues to work normally. Then you can close the hanged app. 
Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsERPf9k54U

Now I don't think this is particularly an advantage of this kind of multitasking. It should be the same thing in the preemptive multitasking, isn't it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pre-emptive multitasking is a way of matching up threads with resources they require when they become available, eg. CPU, disk, NIC, KB, mouse. Most such systems have a timer driver that may cause preemption if the machine is overloaded with threads that are waiting only for CPU, ie. more ready threads than cores. Pre-emptive designs were not developed just to 'time-slice' between ready threads, they were designed to give good I/O performance.  If such a box is regularly 'time-slicing' between ready threads, it is overloaded and operating inefficiently.

Comment: An operating that schedules based on thread priority also dynamically adjusts the priority of the threads, based on long they haven't had a chance to execute.  That solves priority-inversion problems and provides a way implement round-robin scheduling.

Comment: @HansPassant - between us, that should cover it, I hope.  It seems that the OP has been reading/viewing the wrong sites.  Not surprising, there are so many of them:(

Comment: @MartinJames James Thank you, I have got the idea, although some terms are new for me because I haven't studied OS, I am just reading about threads in java. That brought that video up and I started watching it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, I have got the idea, although some terms are new for me because I haven't studied OS, I am just reading about threads in java. That brought that video up and I started watching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preemptive, multitasking and priority (scheduling) are different aspects of the OS concepts.

Preemptive, in the context of process scheduling, is a strategy in which the OS can preempt (take) the resources allocated for a process whenever it (the OS) need. In contrast, non-preemptive scheduling strategy cannot preempt (take back) the resources until the process finishes using them and release them.

A priority scheduling algorithm can be implemented with preemptive or non-preemptive strategy.